# Using low-discrepancy sequence for bernoulli trials in MC sim

Tags: r, monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

I need to generate binomial distribution random numbers for my Carlo simulation (I need Bernoulli trials for a parameter). Thus far, I've used R "rbinom" function for that. However, as I understand, I can more effectively use the parameter space by utilizing a low-discrepancy sequence for generating random numbers.

Is it possible to use Sobol sequence to generate Binomial random numbers? Or does it even make sense? If yes, then how to convert the sobol sequence to bernoulli or binomial distribution?

Thanks!